# Inconsistent indentation: SaSS

Tags: html, css, sass

First time user of SASS.Working on SASS main file. Made a mixins and included it on styles but it shows me error:- 
 app.sass (Line 58: Inconsistent indentation: 5 spaces were used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 2 spaces).

Last line of code is line 58(+circleThing)
 Below is my code for app.sass

```
    =circleThing($rad, $height, $width, $bg, $colour)
-webkit-border-radius: $rad
-moz-border-radius: $rad
-ms-border-radius: $rad
border-radius: $rad

height: $height
width: $width

line-height: $height
text-align: center

background: $bg
color: $colour

margin: 0 auto

header
     +circleThing(100%, 200px, 200px, $blue, white)
```

Comment: Make sure you're using the preprocessor scss or sass?